# User authentication failure when using Dojo and Spring Security due to failure to verify CSRF token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, dojo

Below is a fragment of my Dojo code verifying the username and password of the user.

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost({
url : "../../j_spring_security_check",
        load : function(response, ioArgs) {
            return response;
        },
        handleAs : "json-comment-filtered",
        timeout : 180000,
        content : {
            "j_username" : usrName,
            "j_password" : password
        },
        error : function(response, ioArgs) {                
            return response;
        }
    });
```

On the server side Spring configuration is:

```xml
<form-login login-page="/service/authenticate" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/service/authenticate" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/service/authenticate" />
```

On attempting to authenticate the user. I keep getting:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.)

on the `xxx/j_spring_security_check` endpoint.

I have enabled:

```
<headers><frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/></headers>
```

The goal is to enable  Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection. Any ideas on how I could solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes had to be made both on the server and client code base.

### Server

This was clearly explained in the link shared. [spring security reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token)

```
<http ...>
  <csrf token-repository-ref="tokenRepository" />
</http>
<b:bean id="tokenRepository"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository">
    <b:property name="cookieHttpOnly" value="false"/>
</b:bean>
```

### Client

Intercepted xhr request and added the X-XSRF-TOKEN header by obtaining the XSRF-TOKEN from the cookie. This works but from a security perspective better alternatives than storing the token in cookie can be used.

```
require(
    ["dojo/request/notify", "dojo/cookie"],function(notify,Cookie ){
notify("send", function(response, cancel) {
            response.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN"));
        });}
```